# Market Information by Company Yahoo RSS Feeds

Tags: php, xml, stocks, yahoo-finance

Yahoo provide feeds in XML format that provide market information.

The following page details news feeds:
http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/company.html

It is proving difficult however to find the market information feeds. Essentially what I want is the value, and change of specific markets, eg. GOOG, AAPL, EBAY etc..

I know the feed exists because it is used by the widgets and apps produced by Apple.

Can anyone find the feed that would then allow us to enter a string containing the companies we want the results for.

Comment: There probably won't be many around that are, *free*.

Comment: @MackieeE The Yahoo feed appear free, I'm simply after the link

Comment: Well, what is wrong with the one, you already provided? http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=yhoo,msft,tivo

Comment: @DainisAbols It doesn't provide *statistical* data; but rather news.

Comment: Check out this blog post I wrote about this idea. You can use PHP to get this data from the Yahoo! Finance YQL API. http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2015/11/how-to-get-stock-quotes-with-php-using-the-yahoo-finance-api

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at the wrong feed (The Yahoo! Finance Company ***News*** RSS) for the information you want. [You should check this link](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm)

For example:

```
 http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GE&f=nkqwxyr1l9t5p4
```

gives you this:

```
"GENERAL ELEC CO",32.98,"Jun 26","21.30 - 32.98","NYSE",2.66,"Jul 25",28.55,"Jul 3","-0.21%"
```